# Match multiple tokens delimited by pipes on a single line of output - expression error

Tags: regex, expression, ksh

I'm trying to match several values from a single line.

Example line:

```
|31=3.8|32=123|43=0|39=a|11=089|21=J|15=ABC|12=D|
```

Ideally I want to extract the values from `31=`, `32=`, and `15=` to give the below.

```
3.8, 123, ABC
```

I've tried using `grep -o` with an expression and what I thought was non greedy substitution as an example.

```
egrep -o "[\|](31=.*?)[\|]"
```

I've also tried using awk with a similar expression.

I think the issue is with my expression because it always seems to return all of the line after 31= no matter what I place after the substring.

I'm using `ksh` if this matters.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with the expression. I'm not an expert at expressions unfortunately.

Comment: Compared to sed and awk, perl works better with regex. You can do this using perl like this - perl -n -e '/\|31=(.*?)\|.*32=(.*?)\|.*15=(.*?)\|/ && print "$1,$2,$3\n"'; 

I tested this with the example u gave and it works fine.

Comment: I doubt this can be done with plain `grep`. With `sed`: `sed 's/.*31=\([^|]*\).*32=\([^|]*\).*15=\([^|]*\).*/\1, \2, \3/'`

Comment: You can not reuse the `|` at the end of a match for the beginning of a new match. With `egrep you can do `echo '|31=3.8|32=123|43=0|39=a|11=089|21=J|15=ABC|12=D|' | egrep -o "[|](31|32|15)=[^|]*"`, but this will not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't use the perl bin on my server unfortunately but I did manage to get the sed working with a | start in front of each tag like |15= so it didn't pick up other numbers.within the values and match those.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ cat phil.awk
BEGIN {
  FS="[=|]"
  OFS=","

  if (!flds) flds="31,32,15"
  split(flds, t,",")
  for(i=1; i in t;i++)
    fldsA[t[i]]=i
}
{
  nr=0
  for(i=2; i<=NF;i+=2)
    if($i in fldsA) {
      printf("%s%s", (nr)?OFS:"", $(i+1))
      nr++
    }
  printf ORS
}
```

Running `awk -f phil.awk myInputFile` results in:

```
3.8,123,ABC
```

Running `awk -v flds='11,12,39' -f phil.awk myInputFile` results in:

```
a,089,D
```